# Summing up periods

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a lubridate period column in my table as the following shows.

```
workerID   worked_hours
02         08H30M00S
02         08H00M00S    
03         08H00M00S
03         05H40M00S
```

What I want to achieve is like sum the number of hours worked by workerID. And I also want it to be in the HH:MM:SS format, even if the hours exceed 24, I dont want it to have the day and instead have the hours accumulate to more than 24.
I have tried working with

```
df %>%
 group_by(workerID) %>% 
 summarise(sum(worked_hours))
```

but this returns a `0`.

Comment: try to convert you worked hours in seconds and summarise it

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package `lubridate` which makes dealing with times a bit easier. In your case, we need to convert to `hms` (hours minutes seconds) class first, group by worker ID and take the `sum`. However, in order to get it in the format `HH:MM:SS`, we need to convert to period, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
 mutate(new = as.duration(hms(worked_hours))) %>% 
 group_by(workerID) %>% 
 summarise(sum_times = sum(new)) %>% 
 mutate(sum_times = seconds_to_period(sum_times))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>    workerID sum_times   
>      <int> <S4: Period>
> 1        2 16H 30M 0S  
> 2        3 13H 40M 0S
> ```

Comment: It worked just fine, but it I have sums that go over one day like this one 1d 15H 25M 0S I need to keep it as HH:MM:SS which is 39H25M00S

Answer (score 0):

There's also a base R solution. I've added a row to exceed minutes and hours.

```
  workerID worked_hours
1        2    08H30M00S
2        2    08H00M00S
3        3    08H00M00S
4        3    05H40M00S
5        2    09H45M00S
```

We could split `worked_hours` at the characters, then aggregate it by worker's ID. After that, we need to subtract full hours from the minutes. Finally we collapse the time with `:`.

```
p <- cbind(p[1], do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(p$worked_hours, "\\D"), as.numeric)))
p <- aggregate(. ~ workerID, p, sum)
p$`1` <- p$`1` + floor(p$`2` / 60)
p$`2` <- p$`2` %% 60
p[-1] <- lapply(p[-1], function(x) sprintf("%02d", x))  # to always have two digits
cbind(p[1], worked_hours=apply(p[-1], 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse=":")))
#   workerID worked_hours
# 1        2     26:15:00
# 2        3     13:40:00
```

---

***Data***

```
p <- structure(list(workerID = c("2", "2", "3", "3", "2"), worked_hours = c("08H30M00S", 
    "08H00M00S", "08H00M00S", "05H40M00S", "09H45M00S")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking. They need the sum